# C++ What's the standard way to define a recursive constructor?

Tags: c++, constructor, grammar, recursive-datastructures

Sorry, I edited my question now .Pay attention to the bold type words .

I really need a recursive constructor while defining a kdtree class .
But I'm afraid I'm not doing it the right way .
How can I do it more elegantly ?

This is my code using the **this** pointer ,**it compiles** and works well .
**Don't do anything at all** ,just **showing the brief idea of what a recursive constructor should look like** .

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class foo
{
public:
  int a, b;
  foo(unsigned int k)//this piece of code just shows the brief idea of what i'm trying to do.
  {
    if (k)
      *this = foo(--k);
    else
      a = k, b = k;
  }
};

int main()
{
  foo f(3);
  cout << f.a << f.b << endl;
  getchar();
}
```

This is my kdtree sample code .**This is what I'm actully trying to achieve** ,still **don't compile** ,I'll edit it later.

```
class kdtree
{
public:
  int16_t count;//数组里面可以只存mask和key生成的unique_key，因为树结构，和count可以后期生成
  int16_t key;
  int16_t mask;
  inline bool is_full()
  {
    return mask + count == 0x8000;
  };
  shared_ptr<kdtree> left, right;
  kdtree(){}
  kdtree(int x1, int y1, int z1, int x2, int y2, int z2, int _x = 0, int _y = 0, int _z = 0, int len = 0, int ikey = 0x8000)
  {
    int i = 0x80 >> len / 3, j = 0x4000 >> len;
    if ((x2 - x1)*(y2 - y1)*(z2 - z1) == j << 10)
    {
      count = j << 1;
      key = ikey;
      mask = ~ikey ^ (ikey - 1);
      return;
    }
    switch (len++ % 3)
    {
    case 0:
      if (x1 < _x&&x2 < _x)
      {
        *this = kdtree(x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2, _x, _y, _z, len, ikey -= j);
        return;
      }
      if (x1 >= _x&&x2 >= _x)
      {
        *this = kdtree(x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2, _x + i, _y, _z, len, ikey += j);
        return;
      }
      left = shared_ptr<kdtree>(new kdtree(x1, y1, z1, _x, y2, z2, _x, _y, _z, len, ikey -= j));
      right = shared_ptr<kdtree>(new kdtree(_x, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2, _x + i, _y, _z, len, key += j));
      count = j << 1;
      key = ikey;
      mask = ~ikey ^ (ikey - 1);
      return;
    case 1:
      if (y1 < _y&&y2 < _y)
      {
        *this = kdtree(x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2, _x, _y, _z, len, ikey -= j);
        return;
      }
      if (y1 >= _y&&y2 >= _y)
      {
        *this = kdtree(x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2, _x, _y + i, _z, len, ikey += j);
        return;
      }
      left = shared_ptr<kdtree>(new kdtree(x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2, _x, _y, _z, len, ikey -= j));
      right = shared_ptr<kdtree>(new kdtree(x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2, _x, _y + i, _z, len, ikey += j));
      count = j << 1;
      key = ikey;
      mask = ~ikey ^ (ikey - 1);
      return;
    case 2:
      if (x1 < _x&&x2 < _x)
      {
        *this = kdtree(x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2, _x, _y, _z, len, ikey);
        return;
      }
      if (x1 >= _x&&x2 >= _x)
      {
        *this = kdtree(x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2, _x, _y, _z + i, len, ikey + j);

      }
      left = shared_ptr<kdtree>(new kdtree(x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, _z, _x, _y, _z, len, ikey));
      right = shared_ptr<kdtree>(new kdtree(x1, y1, _z, x2, y2, z2, _x, _y, _z + i, len, ikey + j));
      count = j << 1;
      key = ikey;
      mask = ~ikey ^ (ikey - 1);
      return;
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Looks pretty nonsensical to me, what do you want to achieve actually?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? You could set a and b to zero right away :-)

Comment: I really don't believe you will ever need such a weird thing. It ought to be an XY problem.

Comment: Why? Why not just set `a = --k;`? Why invent this non-existent syntax?

Comment: @EJP Is it non-existent?

Comment: If you're trying to create a recursive data structure, you're going about it in a completely wrong way.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider Recursive constructors are non-existent. He isn't using one, but he's trying to.

Comment: @EJP I am not sure about that (I actually think what the OP does is not illegal, it's just nonsensical) but even if, it's not a syntax/grammar issue. The code compiles just fine.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Edited my question ,would you please help me?Thank you .

Comment: @iouvxz Instead of overwriting `*this` you probably want to set `this->left` and `this->right` using `new kdtree(....)`.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Why?*this = kdtree(...) works well ,recursive construction keeps my code clear and clean ,what's the problem if I insist on doing this ?

Comment: @iouvxz _"what's the problem if I insist on doing this ?"_ That you simply loose your formerly created `kdtree` instances.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Why? You mean *this = kdtree(...) ,the constructed kdtree will be lost ?It contains shared_ptrs and integers ,it can't be lost .

Comment: @iouvxz Do what you want :P ...

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Thank you ,I'll try .If this leads to any kind of problem ,I'll rewrite it in a loop instead of a  tail recursion.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ This function would at most recursive 15 times in my case .

Comment: Just a side-note: Your function `is_full()` is undefined behavior. It assumes that signed integers wrap-around, but this is not imposed by the standard. The compiler would be free to optimize this code in any way, e.g. by just returning false. You should also prefer unsigned types if you do bit operations such as `~`.

Comment: @Jens Thank you very much .You are right ,I should use uint16_t instead of int16_t .

Answer (score 1):

A constructor only builds one thing, so you can't use a constructor to build a group of things.

If you use new Class[ 20]; // 20 Classes get allocated, but each is constructed once in the constructor.

```
class Class
{
    Class * left;
    Class * right;
    Class(  SomeObject & x )
    {
         eatSomeData( x );
         left = nullptr;
         right = nullptr;
         if (x->buildleft() )
             left = new Class( x );
         if (x->buildright() )
             right = new Class( x );
    }
};
```

At each call to the constructor, the constructor only deals with the object it is creating, the fact it is doing this recursively (based on the data in x), is sort of different.  In this case the class is heavily bound into the tree, and can't be easily constructed without building a tree.  Yes it is possible (from comments), but really really not advisable.

If you have a group of items you want to store (e.g. a tree), the typical building blocks are

1. `Item` - the thing (object) you store in the tree.
2. `Node` - an object which understands the tree, and how to traverse the tree.
3. `TreeContainer` - an object which holds the top of the tree, and which knows how to find stored `Item`s
4. `Builder` - an object or function which takes your data and adds it into the tree by calling methods of the `TreeContainer`

Comment: "you can't use a constructor to build a group of things." I think this claim is easily refutable ;-).

Comment: On a more serious side, I don't see why it should be impossible to even build a number of the actual things the ctor is building; like, a node ctor creates a whole tree, calling itself a couple times and assigning the addresses of the created nodes to the proper branch pointers. That's probably what the OP tries to achieve.

Comment: I also think you can fold all these roles into a single node class, if you must; the distinctions you make are logical rather than language-imposed.